# Using normal functions in JavaScript to create inheritance structures

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

So, I'm reading John Resig's Secrets of a JavaScript Ninja, and watching Doug Crockford's talk on ECMAScript 5, looking at browser support for Object.create() and wrestling with how best to work with objects and inheritance in JavaScript.

I came up with what I think is a simple way to create objects and inheritance, and I just wanted to ask if I'm completely overlooking some pitfalls and such. Ok here's some code:

```
// OOP - game enemy example

// Let's create a base enemy type, and two enemies that inherit from it.
// Enemies must be kept track of (how many have been "instantiated").
// Enemies will need to have HP, speed and names.
// Enemies will need to be able to take damage independent of other enemies.
// It must be possible to cause all enemies to double HP and speed or halve them.

// Enemy
function Enemy (name) {
  var enemy = {};
  enemy.name = name;
  enemy.currentHp = Enemy.baseHp * 100; // basic enemies have 100 hit points
  enemy.currentSpeed = Enemy.baseSpeed * 5; // basic enemies have 5 speed
  enemy.hp = Enemy.hp;
  enemy.speed = Enemy.speed;
  Enemy.count += 1; // Count each instantiated bad guy
  return enemy;
}
// Enemy properties (these are the same for all enemies)
Enemy.count = 0;
Enemy.baseHp = 1; // if we change this to 1.3 or .5 all the enemies in the game will be boosted or deminished...
Enemy.baseSpeed = 1; // ...same here.
// getter and setter for hp
Enemy.hp = function (value) {
  if (!!value) {
    return this.currentHp = ((this.currentHp * Enemy.baseHp) + value);
  }
  return this.currentHp * Enemy.baseHp;
};
// getter and setter for speed
Enemy.speed = function (value) {
  if (!!value) {
    return this.currentSpeed = ((this.currentSpeed * Enemy.baseSpeed) + value);
  }
  return this.currentSpeed * Enemy.baseSpeed;
};

// Trio enemy
function Trio (name1, name2, name3) {
  var trio = Enemy();
  trio.name = [name1, name2, name3];
  trio.currentHp = Enemy.baseHp * 30; // trios have less hp...
  trio.currentSpeed = Enemy.baseSpeed * 10; // ...but more speed
  Enemy.count += 3; // they raise the enemy count by three
  return trio;
}

// Boss enemy
function Boss (name) {
  var boss = Enemy(null);
  boss.name = name;
  boss.currentHp = Enemy.baseHp * 300; // Bosses have lots of hp...
  boss.currentSpeed = Enemy.baseSpeed * 1; // ...but they're super slow
  Enemy.count += 1;
  return boss;
}
```

So, am I missing something, or am I meeting my criteria? Is there a massive performance hit using normal functions over constructors and "new"? Or Object.create for that matter? I am overloading memory somehow? I'm pretty sure any functions that are identical for every enemy I'm only creating in memory once with Enemy.someMethod. Would love some feedback. If I need to adjust attributes like enumerable or writable I can use Object.defineProperties (or Object.create with both parameters) within my "fake" constructors, right? Like this...

```
// Flyer
function Flyer (name) {
  var flyer = Enemy();
  // Using Object.defineProperties to assign attributes to properties.
  Object.defineProperties(flyer, {
    name: {value: name, enumerable: true},
    currentHp: {value: Enemy.baseHp * 50, writable: true, enumerable: true},
    currentSpeed: {value: Enemy.baseSpeed * 3, writable: true, enumerable: true},
  });
  Enemy.count += 1;
  return flyer;
}
```

Would love to hear your thoughts.

Comment: This isn't usually the right place to ask for opinions, for that there's [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com); to me your code looks okay, if you're still worried why not run it through jsperf?

Comment: Thanks so much! Hmm... never used jsperf, I'll try that out!